# Howto check a type for the existence of parameterless operator()

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, c++11

I'm trying to check whether a functor is compatible with a given set of parametertypes and a given return type (that is, the given parametertypes can be implicitely converted to the actual parametertypes and the other way around for the return type). Currently I use the following code for this:

```
    template<typename T, typename R, template<typename U, typename V> class Comparer>
    struct check_type
    { enum {value = Comparer<T, R>::value}; };

    template<typename T, typename Return, typename... Args>
    struct is_functor_compatible
    {
        struct base: public T
        {
            using T::operator();
            std::false_type operator()(...)const;
        };
        enum {value = check_type<decltype(std::declval<base>()(std::declval<Args>()...)), Return, std::is_convertible>::value};
    };
```

`check_type<T, V, Comparer>`
This works quite nicely in the majority of cases, however it fails to compile when I'm testing parameterless functors like `struct foo{ int operator()() const;};`, beccause in that case the two `operator()` of base are apperently ambigous, leading to something like this:

```
error: call of '(is_functor_compatible<foo, void>::base) ()' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
note: std::false_type is_functor_compatible<T, Return, Args>::base::operator()(...) const [with T = foo, Return = void, Args = {}, std::false_type = std::integral_constant<bool, false>]
note: int foo::operator()() const
```

So obvoiusly I need a different way to check this for parameterless functors. I tried making a partial specialization of `is_functor_compatible` for an empty parameterpack, where I check if the type of `&T::operator()` is a parameterless memberfunction, which works more or less. However this approach obviously fails when the tested functor has several `operator()`.

Therefore my question is if there is a better way to test for the existence of a parameterless `operator()` and how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I want to test if a given expression is valid for a type, I use a structure similar to this one:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_callable_without_parameters {
private:
    template <typename T1>
    static decltype(std::declval<T1>()(), void(), 0) test(int);
    template <typename>
    static void test(...);
public:
    enum { value = !std::is_void<decltype(test<T>(0))>::value };
};
```

Comment: seems to work so far , but since I'd like to understand the code, could you explain what exactly this `decltype(std::declval<T1>()(), void(), 0)` is doing?

Comment: @Grizzly The first part is for SFINAE on the expression we're looking for. The `0` at the end is to have an `int` return type, because in case the `std::declval<T1>()()` part has `void` as return type, you wouldn't be able to distinguish the overloads. And the `void()` in the middle is to prevent nasty things because of overloaded comma operators.

Comment: that works for the non parameterless case too (using `std::declval<T1>()(std::declval<Args>()...)`), so I don't even have to specialize for parameterless constructors, so thanks a lot

Comment: @Grizzly yes this is easily adaptable to any expression you want :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like:

```
template<size_t>
class Discrim
{
};

template<typename T>
std::true_type hasFunctionCallOper( T*, Discrim<sizeof(T()())>* );

template<typename T>
std::false_type hasFunctionCallOper( T*, ... );
```

After, you discriminate on the return type of 
`hasFunctionCallOper((T*)0, 0)`.

EDITED (thanks to the suggestion of R. Martinho Fernandes):

Here's the code that works:

```
template<size_t n>
class CallOpDiscrim {};

template<typename T>
TrueType hasCallOp( T*, CallOpDiscrim< sizeof( (*((T const*)0))(), 1 ) > const* );
template<typename T>
FalseType hasCallOp( T* ... );

template<typename T, bool hasCallOp>
class TestImpl;

template<typename T>
class TestImpl<T, false>
{
public:
    void doTellIt() { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << " does not have operator()" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
class TestImpl<T, true>
{
public:
    void doTellIt() { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << " has operator()" << std::endl; }
};

template<typename T>
class Test : private TestImpl<T, sizeof(hasCallOp<T>(0, 0)) == sizeof(TrueType)>
{
public:
    void tellIt() { this->doTellIt(); }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the compiler doesn't like `T()()` (not suprising so I tried using `std::declval<T>()()` instead, but `hasFunctionCallOper((T*)0, 0)` never seems to match the first function, even if the operator() exists

Comment: @Grizzly I'll admit that I didn't test it; I *have* used something similar for named functions.  (But perhaps the expression in the `sizeof` was more along the lines of `(*((T*)0))()`  Otherwise, it will fail if there is no default constructor as well.)  Exceptionally, my response here was only a suggestion of something you might try; I didn't have time to experiment myself, in order to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @Grizzly OK.  I've tested it.  It works for all return values except void; `sizeof` of a `void` doesn't work. So I'll defer to R. Martinho Fernandes: using `sizeof( (*((T const*)0))(), 1 )` works (or drop the `const` if you want only non-const `operator()`).  I'll edit my posting to add the code that works (but the credit really goes to Martinho, for the idea of using the comma operator followed by an integer).