# Is it good practice to use the comma operator?

Tags: c++, c, operators

I've recently (only on SO actually) run into uses of the C/C++ comma operator.  From what I can tell, it creates a sequence point on the line between the left and right hand side operators so that you have a predictable (defined) order of evaluation.

I'm a little confused about why this would be provided in the language as it seems like a patch that can be applied to code that shouldn't work in the first place.  I find it hard to imagine a place it could be used that wasn't overly complex (and in need of refactoring).

Can someone explain the purpose of this language feature and where it may be used in real code (within reason), if ever?

Comment: Here's a clever use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905905/howto-check-a-type-for-the-existance-of-parameterless-operator/7906060#7906060

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Clever? I think you are missing the big picture. There's nothing clever in "advanced" C++ metaprogramming, just sado-masochism.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It can be useful in the condition of `while()` loops:

```
while (update_thing(&foo), foo != 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This avoids having to duplicate the `update_thing()` line while still maintaining the exit condition within the `while()` controlling expression, where you expect to find it.  It also plays nicely with `continue;`.

It's also useful in writing complex macros that evaluate to a value.

Comment: Thanks everyone :) It's funny, I've actually used it in loops before without thinking but it never occurred to me that it was an operator until I asked this question.  (I know, it's obvious so I feel a little silly! :p)

Comment: Similarly, I've seen `while (update_thing(y), test_thing(y))`. It allows you to separate the update and the test into two separate functions for better readability, and is still understandable at the loop -- while (oh wait let's update this thing, ok now--) this thing tests true, do this stuff.

Answer (score 10):

The comma operator just separates expressions, so you can do multiple things instead of just one where only a single expression is required. It lets you do things like

```
             (x)              (y)
for (int i = 0, j = 0; ...; ++i, ++j)
```

Note that `x` is not the comma operator but `y` is.

You really don't have to think about it. It has some more arcane uses, but I don't believe they're ever absolutely necessary, so they're just curiosities.

Answer (score 7):

Within `for` loop constructs it can make sense.  Though I generally find them harder to read in this instance.

It's also really handy for angering your coworkers and people on SO.

```
bool guess() {
  return true, false;
}
```

Comment: A comma in variable declarations is *not* a use of the comma *operator*, which produces values.

Answer (score 6):

Playing Devil's Advocate, it might be reasonable to reverse the question:

> Is it good practice to *always* use the semi-colon terminator?

Some points:

- Replacing most semi-colons with commas would immediately make the structure of most C and C++ code clearer, and would eliminate some common errors.
- This is more in the flavor of functional programming as opposed to imperative.
- Javascript's 'automatic semicolon insertion' is one of its controversial syntactic features.

Whether this practice would increase 'common errors' is unknown, because nobody does this.

But of course if you did do this, you would likely annoy your fellow programmers, and become a pariah on SO.

**Edit:**  See [AndreyT's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1618867/318716) excellent 2009 answer to [Uses of C comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1613230/318716). And [Joel 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19224/318716) also talks a bit about the two parallel syntactic categories in C#/C/C++.

As a simple example, the structure of `while (foo) a, b, c;` is clear, but `while (foo) a; b; c;` is misleading in the absence of indentation or braces, or both.

**Edit #2**: As [AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1618867/318716) states:

> [The] C language (as well as C++) is historically a mix of two completely different programming styles, which one can refer to as "statement programming" and "expression programming".

But his assertion that "in practice ***statement*** programming produces ***much*** more readable code" [emphasis added] is patently *false*. Using his example, in your opinion, which of the following two lines is more readable?

```
a = rand(), ++a, b = rand(), c = a + b / 2, d = a < c - 5 ? a : b;
a = rand(); ++a; b = rand(); c = a + b / 2; if (a < c - 5) d = a; else d = b;
```

**Answer**: They are ***both*** unreadable. It is the *white space* which gives the readability--hurray for Python!. The first is shorter. But the semi-colon version does have more pixels of *black space*, or *green space* if you have a Hazeltine terminal--which may be the real issue here?

Comment: It is always interesting to consider the contrary positions but that said I'd like to see more evidence for your points as in most cases the semantic difference between , and ; is quite small. Except that for (;;) a, b, c is quite different to for (;;) a; b; c;

Comment: @Bowie: I don't have any evidence, as I admit in the answer. But your two examples are good: the first `for (;;) a, b, c;` is clear, but the second `for (;;) a; b; c;` is misleading in the absense of indentation or of braces or of both.

Comment: Now that the `Occupy Wall Street` movement seems to be fading, perhaps we can turn our attention back to the vital issue of commas?

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is saying that it is often used in a for loop, and that's true.  However, I find it's more useful in the condition statement of the for loop.  For example:

```
for (int x; x=get_x(), x!=sentinel; )
{
    // use x
}
```

Rewriting this without the comma operator would require doing at least one of a few things that I'm not entirely comfortable with, such as declaring x outside the scope where it's used, or special casing the first call to `get_x()`.

I'm also plotting ways I can utilize it with C++11 constexpr functions, since I guess they can only consist of single statements.

Comment: You could write `(x=get_x())!=sentinel`, but I find your way clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only common example is the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 3; i < 10 ; ++i, ++j)
```

As mentioned in the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4db.html):

> Once in a while, you find yourself in a situation in which C expects a
>   single expression, but you have two things you want to say. The most
>   common (and in fact the only common) example is in a for loop,
>   specifically the first and third controlling expressions.

Comment: In the first part (in your example) it's not a comma operator.

Comment: @MByD: That's a comma, but it's not using the comma operator.  The comma is allowed where declaring several variables.  The part on the right _is_ the commma operator though.

Comment: Mine was just a remark as the citation was about first and third parts. Probably, given that citation, it would have been better leaving declaration of `i` and `j` outside the for (as it would be necessary in `C`) leaving just a double initialization inside.

Answer (score 1):

The only reasonable use I can think of is in the `for` construct

```
for (int count=0, bit=1; count<10; count=count+1, bit=bit<<1)
{
    ...
}
```

as it allows increment of multiple variables at the same time, still keeping the `for` construct structure (easy to read and understand for a trained eye).

In other cases I agree it's sort of a bad hack...

Comment: `count = count + 1`? `bit = bit << 1`?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Yup. The original version was `count++,bit<<=1` but I thought it was more readable this way.

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator is useful for putting sequence in places where you can't insert a block of code. As pointed out this is handy in writing compact and readable loops. Additionally, it is useful in macro definitions. The following macro increments the number of warnings and if a boolean variable is set will also show the warning.

```
#define WARN if (++nwarnings, show_warnings) std::cerr
```

So that you may write (example 1):

```
if (warning_condition)
    WARN << "some warning message.\n";
```

The comma operator is effectively a poor mans lambda function.

Comment: Yes it probably is @kaizer.se but I have come to value pragmatism and the macro gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I also use the comma operator to glue together related operations:

```
void superclass::insert(item i) {
  add(i), numInQ++, numLeft--;
}
```

Comment: Would it be any different if `,` would be replaced by `;` in your example? It looks slightly different (very slightly, though) but what does "to glue together" mean in that context?

Comment: it wouldn't make a difference here. But would here: `while (1) ++i, ++j`. Glue together means logically grouping these statements so that it is clear these operations are tightly related.

Answer (score 0):

Though posted a few months after C++11 was ratified, I don't see any answers here pertaining to `constexpr` functions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27324574/1136311) to a not-entirely-related question references a discussion on the comma operator and its usefulness in constant expressions, where the new `constexpr` keyword was mentioned specifically.

While C++14 did relax some of the restrictions on `constexpr` functions, it's still useful to note that the comma operator can grant you predictably ordered operations within a `constexpr` function, such as (from the aforementioned discussion):

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T my_array<T>::at(size_type n)
{
    return (n < size() || throw "n too large"), (*this)[n];
}
```

Or even something like:

```
constexpr MyConstexprObject& operator+=(int value)
{
    return (m_value += value), *this;
}
```

Whether this is useful is entirely up to the implementation, but these are just two quick examples of how the comma operator might be applied in a `constexpr` function.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the already useful answers, one place where I use it regularly, is in assert statements, to trigger error conditions much earlier, when debugging or when the assert statements are compiled in.

E.g.

```
assert((chunk->header = 0, 1)); // Clear header when debugging.
```

I find it more appealing than sprinkling the following all over the code.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
chunk->header = 0; // Clear header when debugging.
#endif
```