# Comma Operator in subscript operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20, comma-operator, subscript-operator

I am quite confused with the comma operator. I have never seen such code with such syntax? but I am curious if it useful at any place? why is it deprecated in c++20?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int  a[5]{1,2,3,45,5};
    std::cout << a[(2,3)] <<'\n';  //  this is work , in c++17 works
    std::cout << a[2,3] << '\n';   // but this is deprecated in c++20 ,in c++17 works
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what research did you do? Did you read the proposal?

Comment: @KamilCuk yeah, I was checking the operator  on cppreference website. I got this syntax. I didn't understand. Why is it working? why it's resulting 45, why not 3? i want to understand in such a way. what is the purpose of such a thing in real life?

Comment: i didn't understand written  thing on.https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: Sounds familiar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qD1aKLux5Fw

Comment: @Bob_ but still I didn't understand why it is not printing 3.why in world people will like to use

Comment: Please note that indeces start from 0. So that in `2, 3` 2 is "ignored" and the element at *index* 3 (which is 45) is selected.

Comment: the comma operator is explained in every C++ book, [did you read one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714)? There are very few [usage for the the comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8219836/995714) and even fewer [clever ways to overload it to do something useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5602112/995714) and deprecating it makes it far more practical in the future

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's important to recognize the difference between comma as an expression operator and comma as a separator between grammatical terms of some kind. They use the same punctuation, but they don't have the same *meaning*.

Within the `{}` of a braced-init-list, individual terms are separated by commas. So `{1,2,3,45,5}` is a sequence of terms. That's a comma-as-separator.

However, within a general expression, the comma acts as an expression operator. When a comma is an expression operator between two expression terms, it means to evaluate the left expression, discard its result, then evaluate the right expression, which is the result of the total expression.

Within a `[]`, a comma is *not* a separator in C++17. Therefore, it acts as an expression operator. `a[2,3]` means to evaluate 2, discard it, then evaluate 3. So the index used will be 3.

C++20 deprecates a comma expression as the direct expression used in a `[]`. It does this so that future versions of the C++ standard will have the freedom to make commas within `[]` become comma *separators* rather than comma operators. That is, `[2, 3]` makes 2 and 3 the parameters to a call to an overloaded `operator[]`.

This is similar to how the parameters to a function use the separator comma. So if you need to use the operator comma on two expressions within a function call, you have to wrap them in `()`: `func(1, (2, 3))`. This function takes two parameters, with the second one being the result of the comma operator applied to its terms.

Answer (score 3):

Prime reason why it is deprecated is that it is hoped to use the syntax in the future for multidimensional subscript operators.

Three  other reasons why it is deprecated you already said:

- It is very rarely used in practice
- People are often confused when it is used what is going on
- People are in difficulty to think why it is allowed

Comment: Oh boy! Can't wait for proper in-the-language multidimensional subscripting!

Comment: @davidbak Can't wait, uh? Use Common Lisp in the meantime! ;)